# Benefits of Using RESTful Web services for Ajax?

Tags: ajax, rest, servlets, service, web

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that many people are using RESTful web services to provide data to Ajax.  However, a normal Servlet or PHP page can easily provide that information to Ajax applications.  So, I don't see the benefit of creating web service, even a RESTful one, to provide data to Ajax calls.

So, my question is: what is the benefit of using a RESTful web service, rather than using a simple Servlet or PHP page to provide response to a Ajax application?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you? In any case, what do you see as the distinction between a "RESTful web service" and a simple servlet or PHP page, and why couldn't a RESTful web service be implemented with either?

Comment: Don't answer a question with a question.  If I knew the answer, I wouldn't be asking it.  No one has put a gun to your head to force you to make a comment.  You don't know the answer yourself, and yet for some starnag reasons you are compelled to make a comment.  If I'm ignorant about a subject, I personally won't comment on it since it makes me look like a fool.  But it's a free society; do what you like even if it makes you look like a fool.

Comment: Wow. And ironic. Please note that Piotr's answer pretty much mirrors my comment, because you make an artificial distinction without providing a reason. I asked my question for a reason--you respond with vitriol and total rudeness. I actually know a fair amount about the subject--which is why I asked for further info.

Comment: I'm not in the habit of creating flames since it is a waste of bandwidth.  But in case you have not noticed starting your comments with "Why wouldn't you? In any case" seems as if you are saying "Don't ask stupid questions".  That's what I call rude.

Comment: I might suggest not starting off by assuming someone is being rude, and is instead wondering "why wouldn't you," because it's relevant, and "what do you see as the distinction", because it's relevant. Without understanding why you believe certain things, creating a meaningful answer is difficult. Even if I *had* been rude, your response was counter-productive and out-of-proportion. You alienated a total stranger, and cast aspersions on my knowledge and helpfulness (in a forum where knowledge and helpfulness is publicly exposed, at least to some degree).

Comment: @DaveNewton Actually, no, you were providing no value in terms of the expectations of those who ask questions on this site, which you could have done by simply answering the question asked. Comments, as Dan stated, serve little purpose, given that people do not come here to _discuss_ matters, they come to have questions _answered_. But then as a long-time user of this site, you know that.

Comment: @NickWiggill Without understanding the OP's *objections* to, or even what the OP believes the (meaningful) difference between a "RESTful service" and a "simple page that responds with data" is, there's not even a starting point to discussion. The answer mirrors my comment as well. (And it's funny that you followed up to a two-year old question and a comment with "little purpose" with a comment with even less purpose.)

Comment: @NickWiggill Your *original* comment, btw, was way out of line.

Comment: @DaveNewton As were all of yours. You can argue till you're blue in the face, but you are a time-waster. As to purpose of my engaging here, if it prevents time-wasters like you from wasting other people's time on this and other SE sites, then I'm happy to pitch in to support those who made a valid point in asking you to be constructive (in future).

Answer (score 2):

[RESTful Web Services](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/) are using the HTTP protocol and HTTP Methods for invocation. RESTful Web Services doesn't have any special protocol like "big" (SOAP) Web Services have.

Therefore, Servlets can be used to create RESTful Web Services as well. In the matter of fact, if you create a simple Servlet with `doGet(-)` method, you've just created a RESTful Web Service serving `GET` HTTP Method invocations.
The same is with your simple PHP page.

If you're referring to RESTful Web Services as an i.e. JAX-RS implementation, than it buys you a flexibility and ease of development (`@Produces`, `@Consumes`, `@FormParam`, multiple `@GET` methods etc.)

Comment: The fact is that there is such a hype made of RESTful web services, that you expect a totally new way of doing things.  

So, I take it that in your opinion, it's a matter of convenient rather than providing us a totally new technology that we use RESTful web services. I do agree with the convenience part.  For example you can turn a POJO easily into a RESTful web service without having to put up with any limitation that Servlets might impose.

Comment: You're right about the hype. Many people just repeats 'RESTful' mantra like it's something new that they 'must have'. And about the nomenclature: it's like the 'cloud computing' hype. What does it mean today? It's so blurred because of marketing guys that it's hard to know what people are referring to each time they say it.