# What is the benefit of RESTful Web Service Vs Using Just a simple Servlet?

Tags: rest, servlets, service, web

Regardless of whether I create a RESTful Web service to be consumed by Ajax in my own pages, or by any user, I can provide the same functionality (data) to the application or user using a simple servlet.

I mean the user or application don't see any different between response provided by a simple servlet or respone provided by a RESTful web service. So, I'm guessing that the benefit is on the server side and to the developers. Can someone please tell me what are the benefits of using RESTful web services.

I appreciate any respone

Comment: Please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651196/benefits-of-using-restful-web-services-for-ajax/8653623#8653623 as I hope it'll help you.

Comment: But convenience can't be the only reason.  Annotations might provide some convenience in Java, but other programming languages don't have annoations, and developers still use them.  So, there must be benefits that I can't see.

Comment: The bottom line is: response provided by the Servlet **is** a RESTful Web Services response. What do you exactly understand by 'RESTful Web Service'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Servlet vs RESTful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874695/servlet-vs-restful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition a webservice is intended to be consumed by any client granted access. If the client you are developing is the only application that you will ever need or want to access the resource then there is little benefit to creating a webservice. However, if you want to make the resource available as a service endpoint for more than just this application in a way that is implementation agnostic then a Restful webservice is a great way of doing it.